# Tkinter Text Widget, iterating over lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

If I have a tkinter Text widget filled with the following:

```
/path/to/file/1.txt
/path/to/file/2.txt
/path/to/file/3.txt
```

Is there a direct way to iterate over all lines (for instance, to open a file, perform an action, and write)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`text_widget.get('1.0', 'end-1c')` returns whole text content as string. Split it using `str.splitlines()`.

```
from tkinter import *

def iterate_lines():
    for line in t.get('1.0', 'end-1c').splitlines():
        # Iterate lines
        if line:
            print('path: {}'.format(line))

root = Tk()
t = Text(root)
t.insert(END, '/path/to/file/1.txt\n/path/to/file/2.txt\n/path/to/file3.txt\n')
t.pack()
Button(root, text='iterate', command=iterate_lines).pack()
root.mainloop()
```